# Left and right padding isn't working

Tags: jquery, css, padding

I've been looking for an answer for two hours.

```
 .liteAccordion .slide > div {height: 100%; position: absolute; top: 0;
 z-index: 10; overflow: hidden; background:
 white;color:black;padding:25px;}
```

Only the top and bottom padding are working. What can be the reason of the problem?

I'm using js horizontal accordion menu plugin from http://nicolahibbert.com/demo/liteAccordion/

HTML CODE

```
<div id="site-accordion">
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <h2><span>գլխավոր</span></h2>
                    <div class="ins">
                        <h3>This is Slide One.</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                            magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                            consequat. <a href="#">Link somewhere</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2><span>նսորություններ</span></h2>
                    <div>
                        <h3>This is Slide Two.</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                            magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. <br /><a href="#">Link somewhere</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2><span>ծառայություններ</span></h2>
                    <div>
                        <h3>This is Slide Three.</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                            magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                            consequat. <a href="#">Link somewhere</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2><span>կապ</span></h2>
                    <div>
                        <h3>This is Slide Four.</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore
                            magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi. <br /><a href="#">Link somewhere</a>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <h2><span>խորհրդակցություն</span></h2>
                    <div>
                        <h3>This is Slide Five.</h3>
                        <p><Div class="cont">
                  <form id="site-contact-form" method="post" action="/index.php">
                    <div>
                      <div class="wrapper"><span>Ваше имя:</span>
                        <div class="bg">
                          <div>
                            <input type="text" class="input" name="contactname" id="contactname" value="" class="required"/s>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="wrapper"><span>Ваш E-mail:</span>
                        <div class="bg">
                          <div>
                            <input type="text" class="input" name="email" id="email" value="" class="required"/>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="textarea_box"><span>Ваш вопрос:</span>
                        <div class="bg">
                          <div>
                            <textarea  cols="1" rows="1" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
                       <input type="submit" value="Отправить вопрос" name="submit" /> </div>
                  </form>

                        </p>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ol>
        </div>

</div>
```

Everything works fine here. But I'm trying to add some padding and it doesn't work.

Comment: Just decrease your slide width by 50px

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the plugin overwrite the padding-left of $('div') in the $('.slide')

[image]

try add a child div inside the   `.liteAccordion .slide > div` and set the child div's padding.